# WSL: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: x86, elf, 32-bit, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to a 32-bit ELF executable on the Windows Subsystem Linux but it fails with the error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Is it because it's a 32-bit ELF file ?
If so, how to exec it under WSL ? (it works fine on a regular 64-bit linux machine).

here's the LEF header :

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 4c 69 6e 75 78 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       76
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8048080
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         2
  Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

Comment: WSL only supports 64-bit programs. That is unlike most regular Linux distros that have the 32-bit compatibility layer built in, WSL doesn't. you just can't execute 32-bit apps in WSL.